# How to avoid stale getters in Javascript when copying (and modifying) an object?

Tags: javascript, getter

I'm trying to allow transformation of a tree structure using a `transform` method that maps the nodes in the tree. The nodes in the tree are defined using `get`-type getters, and these don't get updated when I make a new copy and transform the node's contained value.

As an example, consider this simplified version:

```
function node() {
  return {
    foo: '123',

    get blah() { return this.foo; },

    transform(f) {
      const copy = {};
      Object.assign(copy, this);
      copy.foo = f(copy.foo);
      return copy;
    }
  };
}

const a = node();
const b = a.transform(value => '456');
a.blah
b.blah
```

The getter in the transformed copy continues to return '123' even after `foo` has been updated to '456'.

What would be the proper way of returning a transformed copy of the object but with the getters referencing the updated object rather than the source?

Comment: Why not just `const b = node(); b.foo = '456';` and get rid of the `transform` function, or just use a constructor or class, since `node()` returns a new Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.assign` will invoke getters; they will not exist anymore:

```js
function node() {
  return {
    foo: '123',

    get blah() { console.log('invoked');return this.foo; },

    transform(f) {
      const copy = {};
      Object.assign(copy, this);
      copy.foo = f(copy.foo);
      return copy;
    }
  };
}

const a = node();
const b = a.transform(value => '456');
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(b, 'blah'));
```

You can copy the descriptors instead with `getOwnPropertyDescriptors`, then assign them with `Object.defineProperties`:

```js
function node() {
  return {
    foo: '123',

    get blah() { return this.foo; },

    transform(f) {
      const copy = {};
      const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(this);
      Object.defineProperties(copy, descriptors);
      copy.foo = f(copy.foo);
      return copy;
    }
  };
}

const a = node();
const b = a.transform(value => '456');
console.log(a.blah);
console.log(b.blah);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the `node` function itself being used to return the copy, i.e. it can create fresh immutable objects with any `foo` value:

```
function node(foo) {
  return {
    foo,
    get blah() { return this.foo; },
    transform(f) {
      return node(f(this.foo));
    }
  };
}

const a = node('123');
const b = a.transform(value => '456');
console.log(a.blah);
console.log(b.blah);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just use a constructor like:

```js
function Node(){
  let wow = 'will not change length'; // I like that
  this.foo = '123';
  Object.defineProperties(this, { //put all getters and setters in here
    blah:{ 
      get:()=>this.foo
    },
    length:{
      get:()=>{
        let l = 0;
        for(let i in this)l++;
        return l;
      }
    }
  });
}
const a = new Node, b = new Node;
b.foo = '456'; a.newProp = 'test';
console.log(a.blah); console.log(a.length); console.log(b.blah); console.log(b.length);
```

but, you might want to use a `class`:

```js
class Node{
  constructor(){
    this.foo = '123';
  }
  get blah(){
    return this.foo;
  }
  get length(){
    let l = 0;
    for(let i in this)l++;
    return l;
  }
}
const a = new Node, b = new Node;
b.foo = '456'; a.newProp = 'test';
console.log(a.blah); console.log(a.length); console.log(b.blah); console.log(b.length);
```

I personally prefer constructors, since you can have private variables in all Browsers.